# Remove duplicates conditionally from array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So i have this array:

```
['One', 'Two', 'One', 'One', 'Three', 'Three', 'One']
```

I want to get this result:

```
['One', 'Two', 'One', 'Three', 'One']
```

So I want to remove items that is the same as previous item.
How to do that in Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)

```
ary = ['One', 'Two', 'One', 'One', 'Three', 'Three', 'One']
ary.chunk {|x| x }.map(&:first)

#=> ["One", "Two", "One", "Three", "One"]
```

> Enumerable#chunk enumerates over the items, chunking them together based on the return value of the block. consecutive elements which return the same block value are chunked together.

```
ary.chunk {|x| x }.to_a
=> [["One", ["One"]],
 ["Two", ["Two"]],
 ["One", ["One", "One"]],
 ["Three", ["Three", "Three"]],
 ["One", ["One"]]]
```

`map(&:first)` [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-map) iterates over the array calling the `first` method on each element of the array

`&:first` is called `symbol to proc` which creates a proc object that map yields each element of the array to

so the example above could be rewritten as below:

```
lambda_obj = ->(ele) { ele.first }
ary.chunk {|x| x }.map(&lambda_obj)

#=> ["One", "Two", "One", "Three", "One"]
```

Comment: Your answer was first, and it is doing what i need, and i guess it is realy great. But it is hard to read and understand the logic of that mapping after chunk, can you please explain the map part?

Comment: Oh... this is not so readable... What do you think about roippi's unswer?

Comment: @BrazhnykYuriy have you gone through my explanation

Comment: Thank you! Great one-liner! What do you think about @roippi's unswer?

Comment: @BrazhnykYuriy it just shows there are so many ways to solve a problem, you can choose to accept whichever you find convenient

Comment: You have done a great job explaining all this magic, accepted! =)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward with `inject`:

```
ary.inject [] do |accum,x|
  accum.last == x ? accum : accum << x  
end
```

Comment: Nice, without fancy tricks, i can actually read the logic from this code. Thank you! I like your unswer. But in general i guess chunk is the proper function for this job...

Comment: Up to the point that in cases like this one, we can also use `#each_with_object`: `ary.each_with_object [] do |e, a| a << e unless a.last == e end`.

Comment: +1 @BorisStitnicky to you.. I like always `each_with_object` one.